# Sqflite table not created

Tags: sql, flutter, sqlite, dart, sqflite

I'm building a simple app which requires two tables in  a database. To create the tables and the database I use the following syntax->

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sql;
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:sqflite/sqlite_api.dart';

class DBHelper {
  static Future<Database> database() async {
    final dbPath = await sql.getDatabasesPath();
    
    return sql.openDatabase(path.join(dbPath, 'users.db'),
        onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE user_profile(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, address TEXT,mobileno TEXT,dob TEXT);CREATE TABLE user_transactions(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, date TEXT, amount TEXT,cart TEXT)');
    }, version: 1);
  }
```

When I excuete a method to add data to the the table 'user_transactions' it gives me an error as 'E/SQLiteLog(24687): (1) no such table: user_transactions
'. The fetching and adding data to user_profile works perfectly fine. I also executed the sql query in db browser for sqlite and no error was found there.I also tried uninstalling the app and installing it again.Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution to create multiple tables in SQLite is this instead of yours:

```
class DBHelper {
Future<Database> database() async {
return openDatabase(
  join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'users.db'),
  onCreate: (db, version) async {
    await db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE user_profile(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, address TEXT,mobileno TEXT,dob TEXT)");
    await db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE user_transactions(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, date TEXT, amount TEXT,cart TEXT)");
    return db;
  },
  version: 1,
);}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just Uninstall the app and re-install the app. Why it works ?

You might already have users.db db created for the app and onCreate is executed when db is created for the first time, so uninstalling and re-installing the app would solve the problem.